# Device goes black and Launch timeout expires

Tags: android

Since I am new to android programming, I am not sure how to write code efficiently hence the reason for this question. I am creating an app. A basic app in which the app generates 10 random math questions and evaluates it from left to right (ignoring orders of operations). E.g. 3+5/2 should equal 4 instead of 5.5.

I am getting the error Launch timeout has expired. I have researched this and found out that its because the main thread is doing too much work. How do I overcome this? My app first does alot randomizing integers, could that be the case?

This is the code. It is pretty long.
P.S. in the display method, i hrdcoded it to display the first elements just to see if it will display.

```
public void initAnswers(String[] questionToBeLooped){


    for(int i =0; i < questionToBeLooped.length; i++){



        if(mathOperations.length == 2){
            runningTotal = evaluateAnswerTwoOperations(mathOperations[0], mathNumbersInIntFormat.get(0), mathNumbersInIntFormat.get(1));
        }else{
            int operationsCounter =0;
            int numbersCounter =1;
            runningTotal = mathNumbersInIntFormat.get(0);
            while(mathOperations[operationsCounter] != "="){
                runningTotal = evaluateAnswerTwoOperations(mathOperations[0],runningTotal,mathNumbersInIntFormat.get(numbersCounter));
            }

        }
        answers[i] = runningTotal;
    }

}
```

Could someone tell me how to write this efficiently and also can you provide some tips to generate fluent and efficient apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what in your code is the cause, but you should offload the heavy work into an `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask` will allow you to execute code in a background thread via `doInBackground` and callback to the UI thread via `onPostExecute`. The heavy work you are doing is probably something around the looping constructs you have.

Keep in mind that you cannot modify the UI from the background, so if you need to update UI, wait until the heavy work is finished and do it in `onPostExecute`.

See the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) on `AsyncTask`.

Also worth noting that `AsyncTask` has a [lot of flaws](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/), but since you are new - it is where I would recommend to start.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for the tip. I just looked at my code after getting some fresh air and just noticed that my while loop in the initAnswers method is a infinite loop by accident. You think this could be the cause ?

Comment: And that is why it's important for coders to take regular breaks! Can't believe I committed that mistake...

Comment: Certainly. We all have been there. Glad you got it working.